# Anchor inside <h1> tag

Tags: html, anchor

I have a little problem, maybe a stupid one, but a problem:

On my page I have a anchor-menue. In the past this worked very well, but now it suddenly stopped working. Interesting fact is that only anchors inside  elements stopped working.

For example:

```
<h1><a name="anchor1" id="anchor1"></a>Nice little headline goes here</h1>
```

This one dosn't work, but this one works:

```
<a name="anchor2" id="anchor2"></a>
```

The website with the problem is: [www.kleinbild.org](http://www.fotograf-in-frankfurt.biz/)

The anchor in code-line **126** on index-page with the ID "**pagetop**" is working pretty well for example, but the one in line **155** with the ID "**anker1**" don't.

I've now tried to put some Text inside the anchor like Luke suggested me, but the result is the same. Little example:

```
<h1><a name="anchor1" id="anchor1">Nice little headline goes here</a></h1>
```

Now the question of all questions is: why? I would be very glad if someone could give me an answere for this little problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or a link to the page you're working on?

Comment: Of course, site is: www.kleinbild.org

Comment: Doesn't work in what way?

Comment: You have no href so the link has nowhere to go.  What do you want the link to do?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect one of the possible issues is that your link inside your h1 tag has no text inside it.

You have this:

```
<h1><a name="anchor1" id="anchor1"></a>Nice little headline goes here</h1>
```

But don't you really want this?

```
<h1><a name="anchor1" id="anchor1">Nice little headline goes here</a></h1>
```

Comment: Ultimately we need more info in order to help you. I'm going to your site but I have no idea which heading or links you're referring to. Please provide the code for a specific section that is causing you trouble.

Comment: Hi luke, i've edited my question and added some more information, hope this helps. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi aklein, I don't know if this is still an issue for you but I took another look at your website. I still don't see how you are expecting this to work. I've taken a screenshot and put it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3799114/anchor.jpg. You will see that your anchor tag with ID "pagetop" is definitely empty and not doing a thing as it has no dimensions and is simply not displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues with your HTML:

- First text should come inside anchor.
- Second you should use `href` attribute inside anchor to make it work.

Your html should look like following

```
<h1>
    <a name="anchor1" id="anchor1" href="/redirectToSomePlace">
        Nice little headline goes here
     </a>
</h1>
```